# Getting/setting security attributes of files on a network share

Tags: windows, security

I am able to get/set security attributes (group, owner, DACL, SACL) of files on a NTFS volume by using the GetSecurityInfo/SetSecurityInfo API. The handles I pass to these APIs must be opened with specific access rights (READ_CONTROL, ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY, WRITE_DAC, WRITE_OWNER) which require certain privileges (SE_SECURITY, SE_BACKUP, SE_RESTORE) to be enabled while creating them with CreateFile, which is no problem at all if the files are located on an NTFS volume, and of course if the calling process has sufficient rights. There is a problem, however, if the files are actually located on a network share - creating the file handles would fail with ACCESS_DENIED(5) or PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD(1314). I guess this is due to the fact that the attempt to create the file handle is actually made on the remote machine in the context of a network logon session which represents my user on the remote machine, and the required privileges are not enabled for that remote process. Is there a way I can get past this limitation, i.e. be able to get/set security attributes of files on network shares?
A similar problem is getting a handle to a directory on a network share. While being able to do it locally (by using FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS), I understand that this particular flag is not redirected to the remote machine, which I believe is the reason I can't open a handle to a directory on a network share. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems I was the one at fault here - I have been testing this case with a user which, although an administrator on my local machine, is a regular restricted user on the file server, which caused all the trouble. You can copy security attributes and open handles to directories on a network share if you connect to it with a user which has sufficient rights on the file server which is sharing the resources.